# Evaluate command only when running tests

Tags: cmake

I need to check if the `mpirun` command is present and exit with an error message if not present, but only when the user tries to run the tests. When just building the main library or executable, this command need not exist.

More generally, how to execute a cmake script when a specific target is invoked? I.e., only when I type `build some_target`, cmake should start searching for certain environment variables, commands, etc.

**EDIT**

Workaround. In my case, the custom target is dependent on an executable, and for the executable I can use `add_custom_command` with the `PRE_LINK` flag. The custom command then displays an error message and calls `exit 1` if necessary and only when the custom target is invoked. However, the `PRE_LINK` option only works on real targets such as executables and libraries, and not for a custom target in general, so I'm still curious how to solve this for the general case.